# Bug footer stuck on safari only

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I've been trying to fix a bug for a while and can't fix it. To give some context I code a website where there is a footer at the bottom of the page. The page contains a 'hidden' component that takes a lot of space (more than the screen size) and is revealed when the first action is taken by the user.

Except that when the action is taken, the safari only footer does not move and remains stuck at the bottom of the initial page when the page has actually grown (because the component has been discovered). And so the component is partially covered by the footer, which prevents a correct use.. There is no this behaviour on Edge, Chrome, Firefox....

Here is the code I use for the layout :

```js
export default function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <div className="w-full space-y-4 h-full flex flex-col">
      <Nav currentPage={props.currentPage} />
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-full flex-grow">
        {props.children}
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can add whatever if needed.
Thank you very much

Comment: Can you replicate this in a codesandbox or something similar ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Unfortunately no